# Mail Server allow sending spam to own domain

Tags: spam, smtp

I am having trouble configuring my mail server (Dovecot and Postfix). The problem is that someone can send spam mails to my address from my own mail server. The server is not open-relay but it seems to be half-open.

Example:

alice@example.de 
bob@example.de

Bad Guy sends spam from:
alice@example.de to alice@example.de

OR from 
bob@example.de to alice@example.de

without needing any password.

Sending spam to others is not possible. I tried sending a mail to my own domain from my own domain via Telnet and it was possible without password. How can I prevent this?

Comment: "There are two scenarios where users don't have to authenticate:
1) You send to a rdcipient who is on the server.
2) You send from a client whose IP is listed in mynetworks in /etc/postfix/main.cf."
More:  https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-to-disable-open-relay-on-postfix.44338/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Postfix from accepting mail from domains it owns, that it didn’t send?](http://serverfault.com/questions/444151/how-can-i-prevent-postfix-from-accepting-mail-from-domains-it-owns-that-it-didn)

Comment: Did you find a way ? we got the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

1) Enable mail loging in /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
mail.*;mail.debug                                               -/var/log/maillog
```

service rsyslog restart

2) Try to find out how these messages are taken by postfix

3) add correct rules to main.cf

something like this:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/accept_my_domains,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/block_recipient,
        check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_hello,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unverified_recipient,
        permit_auth_destination,
        reject
```

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of looking at logs, it's a matter of understanding the first comment